# What does Joint entropy really tells us?

Tags: probability, entropy, information-theory

I have two sequences of data A and B.

A = [sunny, sunny, cloudy, rainy, sunny, sunny] with entropy 1.25 bits

b = [hot, hot, cold, cold, cold, hot] with entropy 1 bits

I have calculated joint entropy, which is 0.81 bits.

**edit: due to the comments joint entropy might be calculated wrong, i put here my method:**

H(A,B) = - SUM P(A,B) * log2(P(A,B)).

```
Sunny,Hot = 0.75 > 0.31 bits  
Sunny,Cold = 0.25 > 0.5 bits
Cloudy, Hot = 0 > 0 bits
Cloudy, Cold = 1 > 0 bits
Rainy, Hot = 0 > 0 bits
Rainy, Cold = 1 > 0 bits
```

Sum of all is 0.81 bits

My question is: What does this really tell me? How could I explain this number in a very practical manner? As you can see joint probability is lower than the entropy of each sequence. What does this mean? Since uncertainty is lower, does this mean joint observation is much more stable in any way?

Comment: Joint entropy should be larger than individual entropies. You must have calculated something wrong.

Comment: Thank you @gunes I have went through calculation all over again, and I think I am correct.

Comment: check this 
out:https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Joint_entropy#/Greater_than_individual_entropies

Comment: btw, how about sharing the joint distribution with us?

Comment: If the values just after $=$ sign are the probabilities of the pair before the sign, they don't add up to $1$. So, this is not a proper joint PMF.

Comment: @gunes Lol, yes you are absolutely correct. I have made a great mistake. Thank you.